# F# Feliz.Bulma dropdown/combobox

Tags: f#, safe-stack

My question is very simple - how to create combobox (dropdown) in SAFE project (using Feliz.Bulma) and populate it programmatically.

In the [docs](https://dzoukr.github.io/Feliz.Bulma/#/) there is no such component. [This](https://github.com/Fulma/Fulma/blob/master/docs/src/Fulma/Components/Dropdown.fs) is the only example (Fulma) I found and can not incorporate it in my project.

Comment: You likely _can_ use Fulma, it returns the same type of react elements that Feliz works with. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried myself)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple dropdown you can use `Bulma.select` in combination with `Html.option`:

```
let dropDownValues = [
    0, "Zero"
    1, "One"
    2, "Two" ]

let dropDown =
    Bulma.select [
        prop.onChange (fun (v: int) -> dispatch ...)
        prop.children [
            for (value, text) in dropDownValues do
                Html.option [
                    prop.value value
                    prop.text text ] ] ]
```

Comment: Actually, `dispatch` in onChange () won't be triggered if your `option` value is int. The `select` expect `string` type value. Please check a working code at https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Feliz/issues/517

Answer (score 0):

I end up using Fulma code:

```
let createManufacturerDropdown (dispatch: Msg2 -> unit) =
let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<Manufacturer>
Dropdown.dropdown [ Dropdown.IsHoverable
                     ] [
    Dropdown.trigger [] [
        Button.button [] [
            span [] [ str "Select Maker" ]
            Icon.icon [ Icon.Size IsSmall ] [
                Fa.i [ Fa.Solid.AngleDown ] []
            ]
        ]
    ]
    Dropdown.menu [  ] [
        Dropdown.content [] [
            for m in cases ->
             Dropdown.Item.a [  Dropdown.Item.Props[  OnClick (fun _ -> SelectedManufacturerName m.Name |> BikeScreenMsg |> dispatch)  ] ] 
                 [
                 str m.Name
             ]
        ]
    ]
]
```